# Bouncing balls won't pause

Tags: java, swing

all
What I'm trying to do is to create a bouncing balls java program. Which I did. Each time the user presses start balls will populate the screen. the only problem I'm having is that I don't know how to pause it. Any help would be appreciated. I tried adding something similar to how I did the addball function but don't know how to apply that to pause the ball. I have tried to do the puase function by adding the button pause but don't know how to get it working

BounceFrame:

```
                import java.awt.BorderLayout;
            import java.awt.Container;
            import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
            import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

            import javax.swing.JButton;
            import javax.swing.JFrame;
            import javax.swing.JPanel;

            public class BounceFrame extends JFrame {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                private BallComponent ballComponent;

                public BounceFrame() {
                    setTitle("Bounce");
                    ballComponent = new BallComponent();
                    add(ballComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

            //      Adds more balls.
                    addButton(buttonPanel, "Start", new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            addBall();
                        }
                    });

                    addButton(buttonPanel, "Pause", new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        }
                    }); 

            //      Closes the panel.
                    addButton(buttonPanel, "Close", new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

                    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    pack();
                }

                public void addButton(Container c, String title, ActionListener listener) {
                    JButton b = new JButton(title);
                    c.add(b);
                    b.addActionListener(listener);

                }

                public void addBall() {
                    Ball b = new Ball(ballComponent.getBounds());
                    RunnableBall rB = new RunnableBall(b, ballComponent);
                    Thread t = new Thread(rB);
                    t.start();

                }

            }
```

RunnableBall:

```
                import java.util.logging.Level;
            import java.util.logging.Logger;

            public class RunnableBall implements Runnable {
                 private Ball b;
                    private BallComponent comp;
                    private static final int DELAY = 3; //Controls speed of the balls.

                    public RunnableBall(Ball b, BallComponent comp)
                    {
                        this.b = b;
                        this.comp = comp;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        comp.add(b);
                        while (true)
                        {
                            b.move(comp.getBounds());
                            comp.repaint();
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(RunnableBall.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }

            }
```

Comment: There is far too much code here on this question.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Condensed the code, made a mistake of including all of it.

Comment: Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the animation, not a Thread. You can stop/start the timer as required.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the ball you need to store the `RunnableBall` object you are creating in some collection variable, such as a variable of type `ArrayList<RunnableBall>`, for example. Then in your Pause button's `ActionListener` you can loop through the `ArrayList` and call a pause method on each of your `RunnableBall`s.

So you'll need to then define a `pause` method inside `RunnableBall`, which sets a boolean variable "isPaused" to true. So then you'll need to create that variable, `isPaused`, inside the `RunnableBall` class, and make it change the behaviour of the `run` method. You should be able to figure that bit out.

One thing you'll need to take care with is the fact that because you're using multiple threads, you'll need the communication between those threads (i.e. the process of setting the `isPaused` variable to true or false) to be *thread-safe*. I think you could achieve that by declaring the `isPaused` variable to be `volatile`, but there are other ways to do it.